# enabling ngrams in Elastic Search on the index created by Titan DB

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, titan, tinkerpop

I have a current setup of titan database with berkey db storage backend and ElasticSearch as indexing backend. The name of the index created is configured in titan and the ES index schema is created through the Titan api only.

What I am looking for is a way to enable ngrams on some specific properties of the vertex which have been indexed in ES.

Does Titan API support any way to enable ngrams in the indexing backend?

Or is it possible to enable ngrams on the index created by Titan in Elastic Search?

Thanks